# Saxon .NET get destination xdmNode from ResultDocumentHandler

Tags: saxon

I am using **Saxon .NET** to transform an **xslt** file with an **xml** file.

This xslt file could use `xsl:result_document()` and **print** to multiple **files**.

---

**Goal**

---

Consider this diagram :

```
                  ------------>  xsl:result_document()
                  |
                  |
xslt  ------------------------>   xml
                  |
                  |
                  ------------>  xsl:result_document()
```

This transform outputs to **3** xml documents, **2** of them being from `xsl:result_document()` and **1** being the normal **output**.

Before these **documents** get onto the **filesystem** , I need to do extra **transforms** on all **3** documents.

However storing all of them in **3** xdm nodes could end up using too much **memory**. I thought of using the `ResultDocumentHandler` but there isn't a way to obtain the **xml data** that would go into the **destination**.

How do I achieve my goals ?

**Thank you**

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking about. Can you clarify what you consider a "destination"? Is that in the meaning of the Saxon (.NET) API? And what kind of further transformation do you want to do, which kind of format do you need or want there?

Comment: In the end its up to your code, the ResultDocumentHandler needs to return an `XmlDestination`, you have the choice of using an `XdmDestination`, a `DomDestination`, a `Serializer`, you just need to make sure you keep them accessible to your code, e.g. with a `Dictionary<string, XdmDestination>` or `Dictionary<string, Serializer>` or similar, to map a URL string to a result.

Comment: If I need to do extra "transforms" literally means XSLT transformations then of course `XsltTransformer` (https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/dotnetdoc/Saxon/Api/XsltTransformer.html) can be used as an (Xml)Destination (as it implements `XmlDestination').

Comment: What I mean by `destination` is a `Xml Destination`. Also I need to do more then one `extra transform`, so I can't just return one `XsltTransformer` as the `Xmldestination` since that would only do one `transform`. Also does the `ResultDocumentHandler` run the transformer if I return it as an XmlDestination ? if so, what `XdmDestination` gets passed in the `Run()` function when Saxon retreives the `XmlDestination` ?

Comment: Do you want to run various transformations on a single result? Or is your statement "I need to do more than one extra transform" referring to the three results you have show, meaning you want to postprocess each of them with one further transformation? Perhaps show some minimal but representative samples of what you want to achieve. Also, have you used ResultDocumentHandler before in simpler settings and are just failing to use it for this task or is it just your first attempt to use it?

Comment: I want to process every single sheet with the same extra transforms. This is my first time using the ResultDocumentHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `Micheal Kay's` answer, If you don't want to use `SaxonCS 11` and pay `money` just to use the `Saxon::Api::IDestination::OnClose()` callback, then you can store the `xsl:result_document()` data in a `dictionary` structure.

However doing so could cause a `stack overflow` is there are too many `result documents`. So my `workaround` would be to `limit` the `dictionary's` size to 1 item.

To do that, every time the `IResultDocumentHandler::HandleResultDocument()` function is called, you can check the `dictionary's` size.

If the size is over then 1, then you need to apply the extra `transforms` on all the previous `result documents` **( you should have the data now )**, as well as output it to the `wanted file`, and then delete the previous `documents` in the `dictionary`.

That way, there won't be a `stack overflow`. However the last `xsl:result_document()` call `requires` you to apply the `extra transforms` by yourself at the end once you get the `dictionary`.

Comment: Have you been running into memory problems actually? Or a StackOverflow error (which is usually not caused by the pure size of the data but rather my infinite recursion)? Or are you only assuming that you cannot work with 70 results to be pushed through your pipeline?

Comment: I am assuming since each sheet is fairly large, and out of memory exception exist in .NET. And I don't have enough time to test if the stack overflow exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you register a ResultDocumentHandler, it will be called every time the stylesheet executes xsl:result-document, and the output of the xsl:result-document is written to the supplied 'XmlDestination`(renamed`IDestination` in Saxon 11). If you want to do a further transformation, then supplying an XsltTransformer to do this transformation seems a good option.

Whatever kind of `XmlDestination` (or `IDestination`) you supply, there are really only two options: the result of processing ends up in filestore, or it ends up in some memory data structure where it can be accessed on completion. Typically this will be a Dictionary or similar that is created by the calling application and is known to your ResultDocumentHandler.

In Saxon 11, it becomes a little easier because `IDestination` allows you to register an `OnClose()` callback which is called when the `xsl:result-document` instruction completes. This allows you, for example, to extract the XdmNode from an XdmDestination at this time, and save the XdmNode in your applications dictionary of results. With Saxon 10, this isn't possible: the XdmDestination itself in the dictionary of results, which might take more memory.

Comment: I guess I will just upgrade to Saxon 11 then, since Saxon 10 makes it impossible.

Comment: Its saying that Saxon 11 NET costs money ??? I can't spend money. what do I do ???

Comment: @iber999, first of all, between SaxonCS (the .NET version of Saxon 11) and Saxon .NET 10 is an important difference: SaxonCS runs with .NET Core 5 and .NET (Core) 6 while Saxon .NET 10 runs under the Microsoft .NET Framework 4. Therefore currently, the first issue to take into consideration as to which version to use is whether you want to write a Windows application for the .NET framework with XSLT 3 or whether you want to write a cross platform app for the new .NET 5 or 6 using XSLT 3. That usually doesn't depend on your budget but on the existing code base.

Comment: Secondly, you can use a ResultDocumentHandler with Saxon .NET 10 HE, the "free" version (as long as you know your .NET code is using the Microsoft .NET framework), it is just a bit different to code you write for SaxonCS. An example (using DomDestination that could use XdmDestination as well I think) is in the sample at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/saxon10/entry/src/samples/cs/ExamplesHE.cs#L1302

Comment: @Martin Honnen If I wanted cross-platform ( which I don't want ), I would just use SaxonJ instead of .NET . I will look into your comment.

Comment: The given sample puts all of the `xsl:result_document()` data into memory `( HashTable )`, I could get a stack overflow with this. **( My application's real `xslt file` does over 70 calls to `xsl:result_document()` )** So I need to process the result documents one by one.